# subdomain URL not accessible through browser

Tags: asp.net, wcf, shared-hosting

I am facing a strange issue.

My ISP has hosted a webservice inside a virtual directory which is placed under a subdomain. now from my system (or network) I cannot access that webservice. Every time I run fiddler, I see a **DNS Lookup for "my_sub_domain.com" failed. No such host is known.**

But If I run it through web-sniffer.com, it is returning as **Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK**

I do not understand what is wrong, Have anyone faced something like this? Is there any problem with my network settings? Can you tell me how to fix this?

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a DNS issue.  Your DNS server doesn't seem to have had the A record for the subdomain propagated to it yet, whereas the DNS server used by web-sniffer.com has had it propagated to it, and thus, can see that it's returning a valid record and IP address.

While waiting for it to propagate to your DNS provider, you could add an entry to your machine's host file with the correct IP address to allow you to continue work.